# Angular 2 / 4 toPromise works but I am having trouble with Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to wrap my head around Observables

Here is what currently works for me with the `.toPromise`

**request.ts**

```
get(url): Promise<any>
{
    //  HARD CODED A URL I FOUND , NOT USING THE "url" param
    return this.http.get("https://conduit.productionready.io/api/profiles/eric").map(response => {
        return response.json() || {success: false, message: "No response from server"};
    }).catch((error: Response | any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }).toPromise();
}
```

That works,

Called from

**event.service.ts**

function ...

```
this.Request.get("/user").then(response => {
        console.log("Got response:", response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Got error:", error);
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("Another response:", response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Got another error:", error);
    });
```

Instead what I WANT TO BE DOING is  Observables

So

I try to "subscribe"

**Subscriber**

I don't really understand how to use "data" and  "subscribe"  etc..

```
 var url = "https://conduit.productionready.io/api/profiles/eric";
    var blah;
    this.getDataObservable(url).subscribe(
         data => {
             blah = data;
             console.log("I CANT SEE DATA HERE: ", blah);
         }
     );
```

**Function to call**

```
getDataObservable(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(data => {
            data.json();
            // the console.log(...) line prevents your code from working 
            // either remove it or add the line below (return ...)
            console.log("I CAN SEE DATA HERE: ", data.json());
            return data.json();
        });
}
```

Comment: no need to add return data.json()

Comment: problem is that i don't understand this ,  can you write up an answer to show me?

Comment: You *do* need to return `data.json()`, or anything else for that matter. `map` is just a lifecycle hook which you can use to modify values in your stream before it gets sent to the subscribers. Take a look as [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423102/storing-observer-in-a-global-variable-and-use-it-later/45423231#45423231) to get a better understanding of how RxJS works.

Comment: what you did with the code, it looks like someone reviewed it and left his/her comments.

Comment: correct,  i lifted it and tried to use it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* examples of how to do this ... here is one:

SERVICE

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

COMPONENT

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

NOTE: This is using the original Http service and not the new HttpClient service.

To understand this code, you need to understand Observables and how Http works. I would highly recommend reading the documentation at Angular.io, working through the tutorial at angular.io, or watching a course such as this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started (you can sign up for a free week to watch.)

Comment: Hi Deb,   I was watching your angular 2 video on pluralsight last year before the september full release ,   I was going to switch to using your updated video , but I was going through the other pluralsight course with cooper /eames  "fundamentals "  i did sort of jump ahead a bit  ... Observables look to be quite awesome -   I need to play with this and try to wrap my head around it    thx Deb

Comment: Cool! The module `Retrieving Data Using Http` covers Observables and Http services. That explains this code in detail. Just be sure to watch the updated course. I did a new version in October for the released version of Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Your service should be like this.So you can subscribe in component

```
getDataObservable(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url).map(data =>  data.json()).catch(error=>Observable.throw(error));
}
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: data.json(...).catch is not a function

Comment: @JeremyMiller sorry missed a bracket next to data.json().corrected the code above

Comment: How can I do an output of console.log inside the .map  ... displaying either data OR data.json     -  i been trying ...

Comment: this doesn't work    `.map(data => { data.json();
                console.log('test', data.json)
            })`

Comment: @JeremyMiller yes