# ionic2- pass a variable from app.component.ts to another component

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm doing long polling and fetching a value from database (whose value changes) and it's saved in a variable called shareVariable in app.component.ts.

I have a component called as header in which I wanna show this value. This component acts like a page header which I inject on every page.
But the value is not getting passed.

Here is app.component.ts

This is the variable I'm trying to share `newNotifications`

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Events, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  socket: any;
  newNotifications:number;

  constructor(public events: Events) {
    this.newNotifications=0;
    this.fetchNewNotifications();
  }

  fetchNewNotifications() {
    // create a new websocket
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
      this.newNotifications = data.user_id;
      console.log(newNotificationCount);
    });
  }
}
```

Code for my common header is:

```
import { NavController, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'common-header',
  templateUrl: `
  <div>{{newNotificationCount}}</div>
  `
})
export class CommonHeader {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events) {
  }
}
```

I don't know why it's not getting shared.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where you are defining `newNotificationCount` in both of your components. Does it compile?

Looks like what you want is some sort of a global variable.

**Method 1 (simplest):**
Define a variable in a separate file and then import it anywhere you want to use it. Example:

`globals.ts`:

```
var newNotificationCount = 0;
```

In other components:

```
import {newNotificationCount} from 'globals';
```

And then you can use this variable anywhere in the file.

**Method 2:** make globals.ts a [service](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/) with `Get` and `Set` methods. This has better encapsulation and you can manage your global variables better if they get out of hand.

**Method 3:** Use [events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events) or [subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423231/1383356): This is specially preferred if you want to do something more than just updating a view, like running a function, as soon as your global value is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Define the Variable as Input in the `CommonHeader`

```
@Input()
newNotificationCount;
```

and pass it in the app.html-template:

`<common-header [newNotificationCount]="newNotificationCount">`