# Angular observable: Why is the parameter undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a question about the `Observable` parameter, in my case, i have a consultService who has the functions `consult()` and the parameter response. The `sendConsultRequest()` function is called before using the parameter response. The sendConsultRequest works just fine because i can see the result in the page, but when i want to export the content by using the parameter response, i have the problem:

> **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataList' of undefined**

In my opnion, the response parameter is already initialized before the export action, because the consultPage works good.
Here is the service code, can you show me why it doesn't work, please?

```
@Injectable()
export class ConsultService {
  private url = 'api/consultApplication';
  response: Application;

sendConsultRequest(id: string) {
  console.log('sendConsultRequest');
  this.http.get<Application[]>(this.url)
    .subscribe(response => {
      response.map(res => {
        this.response = res;
        this.updateApplication(res);
      }),
        pipe(catchError(this.handleError('sendConsultRequest', [])));
    });
}
```

Here is the export page ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ExportComponent init');
  console.log(this.consultService.response);
  this.application = this.consultService.response;

  this.appID= this.consultService.response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field)
      ? this.consultService.response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field).value : null;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: But wait... How do you want to get response immediatelly if you sent async request?

Comment: I don't want to get the response immediatelly, in fact, i have 2 steps, 1st: consult, which will call the function request and initialize the property Response, then the 2nd, the export, which will use the property Response. The 1st step is always good, i think the property Response should be initialized, but no.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you get a `Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` error, this means the object you are trying to read data from was never assigned a value.

In JavaScript, if you don't set something it will always default to `undefined`.

```
let foo; // foo is undefined
```

Also, if you are expecting an argument from a function but that argument was never assigned a value, it too, will be undefined.

```
function foo(arg) {
   console.log(foo);
}

foo(); // the console logs 'undefined'
```

So it is a good rule of thumb that when you get these sort of errors, it means the variable was never assigned a value in your code and you should look to where you *think* you are assigning it a value and re-read the code to make sure it is actually working how you want it to.

This line:

```
this.appID= this.consultService.response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field)
  ? this.consultService.response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field).value : null;
```

Will not work in this case because `this.consultService.response` is undefined. You can only call that logic after `this.consultService.response` is assigned a value.

The reason it is undefined is because you make an asynchronous HTTP call, and then you try to access the value right away. But the HTTP call has not returned yet so your value will be undefined.

If you want to receive the value from the asynchronous HTTP call, you should return the observable from your service and then subscribe to it in your component.

Service:

```
sendConsultRequest(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<Application[]>(this.url).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      return response.map(res => {
        this.response = res;
        this.updateApplication(res);
      })
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError('sendConsultRequest', []))
  );
}
```

Now inside your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.consuleService
        .sendConsuleRequestId(id)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.appID = response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field) ? response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field).value : null;
        });
}
```

**UPDATE** (showing `ReplaySubject` example) - not tested:

Service:

```
consultStream: ReplaySubject = new ReplaySubject();
consult$: Observable<Consult> = this.consultStream.asObservable();

constructor() {
     this.sendConsultRequest(1);
}

sendConsultRequest(id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<Application[]>(this.url)
      .subscribe((consult: Consult) => this.consultStream.next(consult));
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.consult$
        .subscribe((consult: Consult) => {
            // ...
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The function sendConsuleRequestId() is already called by another page, i don't want to call it for the second time, can i subscribe just the parameter response?

Comment: In this case, what you should do is create an observable stream on your service. When you call `sendConsuleRequestId`, add the response result to the observable stream and then you can subscribe to that stream from any component. Make sure it's a `ReplaySubject` so you can get it over and over again even if another component already subscribed to it. If you need help with this let me know, but try it out first. Here's example of creating an observable stream from a subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423102/storing-observer-in-a-global-variable-and-use-it-later/45423231#45423231

Comment: i tried this, but i got always undefined value, i set the subject to new replaySubject(1) should i call again the next() function?

Comment: In consultService i call this.applicationReplaySubject.next(application) during the first step consult, then during the second step export, i subscribe this subject in the constructor, but i got always undefined param error.

Comment: @pierre Make sure you give the ReplaySubject a value *before* you try to subscribe to the observable in your component. I will put example above in my answer.

Comment: Normally the ReplaySubject is initialized, it works like this: 1st: We click on the button, to call sendConsultRequest which returns noting but update the applicationSubject and applicationReplaySubject with response, the applicationSubject is subscribed by ConsultPage and applicationReplaySubject is subscribed by Exportpage, we can open ExportPage via ConsultPage.

Comment: 1st step: call sendConsultRequest(). 2nd step: open consultPage. 3rd step: open exportPage to export a pdf file.

Comment: Hello, thank you, i put the new code below, can you give me some advices, please?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code that is broken, and I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the way it works.

Here is how it works.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConsultService {
  private url = 'api/consultApplication';
  response: Application;

sendConsultRequest() {
  console.log('sendConsultRequest');
  return this.http.get<Application[]>(this.url)
}
```

In your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ExportComponent init');
  console.log(this.consultService.response);

  this.consultService.sendConsultRequest().subscribe(
    response => {
      response.map(res => {
        this.consultService.updateApplication(res);
        this.appID = response.dataList.find(pair => 'PROCEDURE' === pair.field); 
      });
    }, error => this.consultService.handleError('sendConsultRequest', [])
  );
}
```

The way you did it, you never call your service (or you did not post the code that does). And since your service makes an asynchronous call, and you want to wait for it, you should make your component wait for it, not your service.

The way you did it, your component doesn't wait for your service to end the call. It just takes a value out of the blue, and this value is likely to equal null or undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much, So i can not save the response locally? i want to just call once sendConsultRequest, and save the result in response, then i want to use the parameter and not to recall the http.

Comment: You should use a `BehaviorSubject` for that. This way, you call your endpoint once, save the response, and store it in your subject. Other components will subscribe to this subject, and get the response. is that what you want  ?

Comment: So i can store the response in subject, THEN subscribe to the subject to get the existing/old value?

Comment: Exactly. Start by creating a subject with a null value, and in your components, subscribe to it. If the value is null, do nothing, otherwise do something. The subject will trigger your subscription every time you call `mySubject.next(value)`

Comment: But the next() function was already called before i open this page, can i get the old value?

Comment: Do you mean that when i open the new page and get the response, i should call again the next() function to trigger the subject change?

Comment: Thank you, i saw that, i put my new code below, but it doesn't work.